# Why super.requestRectangleOnScreen error in logcat?

Tags: android, webview

Seeing this error in logcat when typing in a password-input text field, in a facebook dialog /webview. Nothing bad seems to happen, but what does it mean?

On each character it shows:

```
E/webtextview(27952): ....Doing a super.requestRectangleOnScreen....
```